# Kivy, AdBuddiz raises the error: __javaclass__ definition missing

Tags: android, python, kivy, ads, pyjnius

I am trying to build my app using kivy, and it is looking great so far. Everything compiles and runs just fine with buildozer.

I am trying to incorporate ads into my app with AdBuddiz according to this website

https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/AdBuddiz-Android-advertisements-integration-for-Kivy-apps

I am stuck in 4th step, as I it gives the error that says

jnius.jnius.JavaException: **javaclass** definition missing

I installed jnius by downloading this
https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius
and used the command: sudo python setup.py install

If you could help me fix this error or help me understand the error, I would appreciate so much.

Thank you.

Comment: You get this error running on the android device?

Comment: No, this error happens on Linux, run on virtualbox. I simply run it using the command

python main.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adbuddiz code won't run on the desktop, you have to run this stuff on the Android device. If you want to run the program without it on linux, put it in an if statement that checks kivy.platform.